# PHP on Windows Server 2008 R2 failure

Tags: windows-server, php

My team is in the process of migrating servers.  As I have recently discovered, this is a real pain.  I think primarily because I just cannot seem to get the server to process the PHP code that works on the previous server.

The server is using Apache.

PHP version 5.6.21 was installed on the new server.

When I view the phpinfo.php on the new server, I noticed that pdo_mysql, PDO_ODBC, pdo_sqlite, pdo_sqlsrv, sqlite3, and sqlsrv are all missing.  Reviewing the old server, all of the "modules" are visible on the phpinfo.php page.

I found this video on youtube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqMZoR-Q-NY

I followed every step in this video.

I downloaded the php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll files, and they are now in the extension folder in the PHP5 folder.

On the php.ini file, I have added the extensions listed above.  Here is what the extension portion of the php.ini file looks like:

```
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll


; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed. 
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php 
;extension=php_snmp.dll

extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
```

Even after uncommenting various extensions, the phpinfo.php still does not display the necessary modules.  The browsers still show PHP code instead of the actual website.

I have also installed the redistributable found here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

I don't really have any idea what I'm doing at this point. I do not know what I am missing.  I just want to get this server running so I can get back to coding.

Comment: Did you restart Apache between changes?

Comment: What is your `extension_dir` directive set to?

Comment: did you look at the php logs to see what happens? just because you have an `extension` line doesn't magically make everything work. the dlls might be not be found. they might be compiled for a different version of php, they might be compiled with the wrong compiler, blah blah blah.

Comment: Yes, I restarted Apache.  Just in case, I will restart it again.

Comment: I don't even see a log folder.  smh.  I'm so lost.

Comment: @ChadSikorra - how do I check where the directive is set???

Comment: It'll be set in the same php.ini file where you uncommented the extensions. Just do a find for `extension_dir`. On my windows box I just have it set to `extension_dir = "ext"` and it works fine, assuming the "ext" folder is in the same path as your php.ini file.

Comment: @ChadSikorra - I found the extension_dir, and it's pointed to "ext" but it's commented out.

Comment: Definitely uncomment that piece then, as I'm pretty sure that needs to be set in your case.

Comment: Have you done a `php -i` on the console, and a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a web app, to see if your `php.ini` changes have taken effect in each environment?